# Why Job entry shows up in Spark UI for RDD with only transformations and no actions

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a text file as the source:-

```
key1,value1
key2,value2
key3,value3
key4,value4
```

I define the following RDD in Scala shell:-

```
 val rdd=sc.textFile("sample.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(x=>( x(0),x(1) )).sortByKey()
```

As you can see, there are only transformations here and no actions. As per Spark's rules of Lazy Evaluation it should not trigger any job. But this declaration itself is triggering a job which I can confirm from a new job entry being made in Spark UI. Interestingly this is somehow being caused by sortByKey operation. I understand that sortByKey would cause shuffling across partitions. But that too should happen only when an action is called ultimately. Another mystery is that if I replace sortByKey with groupByKey, it does not trigger a job even though both these operations would cause shuffling. So two key concerns here.

1. Why the transformation sortByKey is causing job trigger?
2. Why groupByKey does not trigger a job and only sortByKey does, when both of these transformations cause shuffling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Because this is a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1021)...simple as that :)